# python for loop iteration

Tags: python, for-loop

I am a newbie in python, just couple of hours since I have first seen it.
So there is a for-loop question:

Let me have a file test.txt, containing the following text:

```
someText
# just another line with no text [\n]
```

Let hello.py contain:

```
import sys
import os


if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    filename = os.getcwd()
    f = filename + '/' + sys.argv[1]
    try:
        fp = open(f, 'r')
        fileList = fp.read().split('\n')
        fp.close()
   except Exception, e:
        print 'raise exception ' + str(e)
    if fileList:
        for line in fileList:
            print ' --> ' + line
```

Well after executing hello.py test.txt I get

```
--> someText
-->
```

The question now, what is the way to iterate to `fileList - 1` in python or just trim the last escaping char `\n` in my `test.txt` after I have placed it in the list?

Comment: `for line in filelist: if line:`? If you're just picking up Python you should use 3.x and I'd encourage you to run through a structured tutorial; you've a few bad practices there already.

Comment: Without changing the rest of your code, just run `strip()` after `read()`: `fp.read().strip().split('\n')`. But other than that, I agree with Jon that you should really read up on fundamental concepts.

Comment: @poke: or use `fb.read().splitlines()`

Comment: @jonrsharpe & poke what is so bad in my code?

Comment: Not using context manager for file handling, old fashioned syntax for error handling, too broad error handling, try block too long, NameError that you don't catch in the error case, string concatenation instead of the various formatting options, ... Also you can literally just iterate over the file handle to get lines, you don't need to read them yourself. Once you have this working, if you'd like feedback, see [codereview.se].

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you suggest any book or tut for  a newbie?? thanks

Comment: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F, https://wiki.python.org/moin/FrontPage#start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify this part:

```
#... your code
for line in fileList:
    print ' --> ' + line
```

By:

```
#... your code
for line in fileListe:
    if line:
        print ' --> ' + line
```

That will do the trick.

Otherwise, you can do many other tricks like for example:

Thanks to `@Martijin Pieters`'s comment:

```
# Return a list which contain the file lines.
fileList = fp.read().split('\n') -> fileList = fp.read().splitlines()
```

Or:

```
# Return a list and ignore the last element
fileList = fp.read().split('\n') -> fileList = fp.read().split('\n')[:-1]
```

Or:

```
# Remove any `\n` from line you're reading
fileList = fp.read().split('\n') -> fileList = fp.read().rstrip().split('\n')
```

Comment: Much better idea: `str.splitlines()`.

Comment: Yes, there is many more ways to do it. I'll add it to the answer. Thanks.